# c# winforms query for hashed password in MySQL db

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Hello i have a problem i have website which has log in and register page. It works good and stores creds in my db correctly. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ1Wt.jpg) Now i need to be able to verify email and password from my c# login form but problem is passwords are hashed and i dont know what to do with it in my form.
I never used hashed passwords in my program so how it worked so far was my winform would take values from @email and @pass and compare it to db where password were not hashed.

```
private void db_connection()
    {
        try
        {
            conn = "my conn string";
            connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            connect.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    private bool validate_login(string email, string pass)
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select email, password from users where email=@user and password=@pass";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (login.Read())
        {
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = username.Text;
        string pass = password.Text;
        if (user == "" || pass == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields Detected ! Please fill up all the fields");
            return;
        }
        bool r = validate_login(user, pass);
        if (r)
            MessageBox.Show("Correct Login Credentials");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Login Credentials");
    }
```

Comment: You should hash the user input _(using the same hash algorithm used to store the password)_ and compare it to the hashed password in the database.

Comment: You would ask for the password, hash it with your routine and then check to see if the username and hash matches in the database.

Comment: You need to actually search and find out what functions does C# have to compare and validate hashes. In normal login, where you encrypt and decrypt passwords, compare and validate to login, you are writing all the logic required, but hash works in a different way. It uses a algorithm to generate algorithm and only that algorithm, exposed to developers via functions can generate, compare and validate hashes. So read about hashes, how it is different from normal encryption and find out what function c# has for hashes.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by others in the comments, you use the same algorithm to hash the user input you already used in the registration form. Then you compare the hashed input to the hashed data in your DB.

Please never store passwords in clear text or hashed with a weak algorithm. Many users always use the same password and if someone gets access to your DB, this obviously is a very bad thing..